# Convert Timestamp to ISO Date

Tags: python, pymongo

I am extracting Data from Mongodb using some date filter. In mongo my date is in ISO format . As i am dynamically adding date from some variable which is in timestamp format(2019-07-15 14:54:53).Getting Empty Result

```
        curs = col1.aggregate([{'$match':{update_col: {'$gte': last_updt }}},{'$project':json_acceptable_string}])
```

I am expecting Rows after filtering but acual its giving empty dataset

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the original string to a datetime object, then use [`datetime.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) to get it in ISO format.

try this:

```py
import datetime

original_date = '2019-07-15 14:54:53'

date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(original_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

iso_date = date_obj.isoformat()

print(iso_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from dateutil import parser as date_parser
dt_obj = date_parser.parse('2019-07-15 14:54:53')
```

where `dt_obj` is an object of standard `datetime.datetime` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromisoformat`.
Try

```
from datetime import datetime 

iso_string = '2019-07-15 14:54:53'
you_date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(iso_string)
```